# Search recursively into an object return is ok, but undefined in the variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I try to create a validation function to validate some dynamic forms. But i got a problem... I'm trying to search into an object for some properties with their values.

There's my code:

```
export default function(form) {
  return (values) => {
    const errors = {};

    Object.keys(values).forEach((key) => {
      let result = searchIn(form, 'name', key); // undefined
    });

    function searchIn(obj, prop, value) {
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key, i) {
        if(key !== prop){
          if(typeof obj[key] === "object"){
            searchIn(obj[key], prop, value);
          }
        }else{
          if(obj[key] === value){
            return obj; // [object]
          }
        }
      });
    }

    return errors;
  }
};
```

In the `Object.keys(values).map` loop, it logs undefined, but just before that, at `return obj; // [object]` it log the object correctly. How can i make it work correctly? I don't understand how it doesn't return the object found in the `searchIn` function.

Thank you

Comment: Should be `return searchIn(obj[key], prop, value);` - you're throwing away the return value when you make a recursive call.

Comment: The recursivity should be stopped when i return something and doesn't re-call the function!?

Comment: No, that won't "stop" anything. The recursive call will return a value, but if you don't subsequently return that value the overall result will be `undefined` as you're currently seeing. Just add that `return` and try it.

Comment: It doesn't work more :S http://pastebin.com/RWLpaKXV This is my code

Comment: *How* does it not work? What goes wrong? Have you tried anything with the browser debugger and/or `console.log()` tracing?

Comment: In `Object.keys(values).map((key) => {
      let result = searchIn(form, 'name', key); // undefined
    });` result = undefined. I console.log `return obj; // [object]` and it return the object i want, but the `let result` doesn't obtain this value.

Comment: I changed `.map()` for the `.forEach()` and it doesn't work either

Comment: Well you're doing that `.map()` call but you're not putting the return value anywhere. `.map()` returns an array.

Comment: I know, that's why i changed it

Comment: Well if you change it to `.forEach()` there's still no net effect. What do you expect that to do? `.forEach()` ignores the return value from each iteration, but `.map()` collects the return values into an array.

Comment: Thank you Pointy! I just reformated all my code

Answer (score 0):

I reformated all my code for this and it works.

```
export default function(form) {
  return (values) => {
    const errors = {};

    Object.keys(values).forEach((key) => {
      let result = searchIn(form, 'name', key); // undefined
      console.log(result);
    });

    function searchIn(obj, prop, value) {
      let keys = Object.keys(obj);

      for(let i = 0; i <= keys.length; i++){
        let key = keys[i];

        if(key !== prop){
          if(typeof obj[key] === 'object'){
            let result = searchIn(obj[key], prop, value);

            if(result !== false){
              return result;
            }
          }else{
            if(obj[key] === value){
              return obj;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      return false;
    }

    return errors;
  }
};
```